# How to make URL clear?

Tags: php, url

How to make my website URLs like this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/**users/5066707/hand-on-cloud**

Comment: *I've searched for* -> Search for: `.htaccess`

Comment: Rizier, this has to be made with .htaccess? I didn't know, thanks! I will search... :D

Comment: `$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`;

Comment: SLY, yes, can be possibly this, but... I forgoted say that the the URL will return 404, there's a solution?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained

Comment: Alex, well, thanks! This I was searching! I will read it, case I got it, I'm grateful!

Comment: Thanks! :D Case no, http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049... I found this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add .htacces file and try something like this.

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^user/Handoncloud$ profile?pr=Handoncloud [L]
```

Read abaut mod rewrite an .htacces.